# Form in spherical surface

Tags: manifolds, smooth-manifolds, differential-forms

I'm asked to find a two-form on $ S^2 $ that is not obtained by acting on a one-form by a exterior derivative. Kind of stuck in this one, happy if anyone could give me a hint.

Comment: You could try the area 2-form.

Comment: I can obtain $d\theta \land d\phi$ by $d(\theta d\phi )$

Comment: But $\theta$ is not a globally defined function.  It is only a multiple-valued function, therefore in fact not a function.  Try to understand first why the 1-form $d\theta$ on the unit circle is not an exact form.